# Spray.io validate json directive

Tags: json, scala, validation, spray, spray-json

Working with Spray.IO, I'm building a service which receives JSON input. 
I want to validate the JSON payload by checking some of its fields.

I'm not interested in validating JSON schema or parsing errors, but to check field values instead like the real type of a field (i.e: Integer vs Float)

I'm not interested in using Scala *require* since this would raise an exception, and that would fail to inform the client **ALL** validation errors found on a single request.

Is there a built-in directive / rejection for this?

I've seen something similar in Play (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/ScalaJsonRequests), and if there's nothing built-in, how would I go to build something myself?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use Scala's require on the case class that the json is marshalling to.  Example:

```
case class AccountSearchQuery (lookupType:Int, lookupValue:String) {
  require(lookupType != 6 || (lookupType == 6 && lookupValue.toLong > 99999), "lookupValue must be a greater than 99999 for lookupType 6 (account number)") 
  require(!lookupValue.isEmpty(), "lookupValue cannot be empty")
}
```

When you try to create the class and one of the requirements fails you'll get an exception.  If this is part of a Spray route the response will be 400 with a body `requirement Failed: [failure message from the require statement that failed]`

Comment: Thank you @Gangstead for your answer. I just edited my question now since I realized yours could be a valid approach, but I would be missing all other validation errors on my request.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the updated question to check all assertions you could get creative with your require statement:

```
case class User(name: String) {
  require(testAll, allTestMessages)
  def test1 = name.length > 5
  def test1M = if(test1) "too short."  else ""

  def test2 = name.length > 10
  def test2M = if(test2) "also too short." else ""

  def testAll = test1 && test2
  def allTestMessages = test1M + test2M 
}
```